# Eclipse keeps losing source location of library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I am doing plugin development in Eclipse. I have a bunch of projects that use a plugin in their dependencies that I use frequently and need to look into its source. This plugin is referenced as a jar in the Plug-In Dependencies.

I have the source code on my local machine, and I attached it to the jar by doing right click > Properties > External Location > External folder, where put in the path to the location.

After I do this, I can access the source code in Eclipse. However, if I close eclipse and open it again, the source attachment is gone and I get the ugly 'Source not found' window again.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: A user may have no connection to your "external folder".

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jars into the Plugin's folder. Open the `plugin.xml`, go to tab `Build` and add the jars to the plugin. Check the jars in the "Binary Build" area. Do the same for "Source Build" with source-jars.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting. I don't want to manually include the jar into the project and don't want to include it in the build. The jar is a plugin that my project depends on (my fault, I didn't specify that in the question).

Comment: @Terry You dont need to. There are two kinds of build: Binary and Source. So there are two kinds of jars: Binary(.class-files) and Source (.java-files used by eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

**Works only for non-plugin JARs**

You could try defining the plug-in JAR as a User Library:

1. *Window* > *Preferences* > *Java* > *Build Path* > *User Libraries*
   Create your library using *New...*, adding your plug-in binary JAR, and assigning your source folder as *Source attachment*.
2. *Project* > *Build Path* > *Configure Build Path...* > *Libraries* > *Add Library...* > *User Library* > add your library from step 1.

**The Plug-in Way**

You should package your source files into a *source* plug-in that has the following line in its `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Eclipse-SourceBundle: my.plugin.one;version="1.0.0";roots:="."
```

For example, if your plug-in is `my.plugin.one_1.0.0.jar` you should also install `my.plugin.one.source_1.0.0.jar` with the MANIFEST line that points to the plug-in binary.

Additional information can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_individual_source.htm).